# Laravel 5.2 Package : Auth methods fail in constructor of controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have added a controller for my package and I need to call Auth methods inside the constructor of this controller but I get the following error :

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
>   Class hash does not exist

Here is my code :

```
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    private $customer;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['add']]);
         $multiauth = config('cart.multiauth');
         if ($multiauth) {
             $guard       = config('auth.defaults.guard');
             $this->customer = Auth::guard($guard)->user();
         } else {
             $this->customer = Auth::user();
         }
    }

    public function add()
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

When I add the code of constructor inside the other functions it works properly but it fails when it is called from constructor of the controller.

I have searched alot for this and found no working solution.

Comment: Have you done a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Is the `hash` class defined or implemented by you? Do you have a custom guard? Is the `hash` class supposed to be called `Hash`? Beware that some os'es are case sensitive while some are not!

Comment: Yes I have run the 'composer dump-autoload'

Comment: No I haven't defined the hash class, it's the default hash class of laravel.

Comment: You seem to fetch the guard config from a config file `auth.defaults.guard`. Check if there is any occurrences of the word `hash` in it and try change it to `Hash` (upper case H).

Comment: This is the value of the 'auth.defaults.guard' : 
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'user',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

Comment: Try mentioning `use Hash; ` in the first few lines of your controller.

Comment: I added 'use Hash;' but it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by adding a middleware :

```
namespace myNamespace\myPackage;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CustomerMiddleware
{
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         $multiauth = config('cart.multiauth');
         if ($multiauth) {
             $guard   = config('auth.defaults.guard');
             $customer = Auth::guard($guard)->user();
         } else {
             $customer = Auth::user();
         }

         $request->attributes->add(['customer' => $customer]);

         return $next($request);
     }
}
```

Then I used this middleware for the 'cart/add' route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'customer'], function() {
        Route::post('cart/add',
                    'myNamespace\myPackage\CartController@add');
    });
});
```

So by checking the $request->get('customer') parameter inside the 'add' method of 'CartController', I have access to information of current user :

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() { }

    public function add()
    {
       $customer = $request->get('customer');
       // Code 
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use middleware in controller __construct , create a functions and use it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need this code to be executed before running the 'add' method. By defining another function I should call the function inside the 'add' method so the customer variable will be set to null since 'add' method does not use the 'auth' middleware.